# Where does -1 in BJT’s Ies equation come from?

Tags: current, bjt

I don’t know whether there is already a question and answer to this but I couldn’t find one yet. Regarding the following information from a text:

[image]

The equation for emitter reverse saturation current Ies shows that the Ies is directly caused by Vbe in non-linear way. But where does -1 in the parenthesis come from?

Comment: Without the "-1", what would be the current with 0 applied voltage? Do you think that would be physically possible?

Comment: No not possible. So is that the reason to zero the left side when Vbe is zero?

Comment: More importantly, what would be the current if the \$V_{be}\$ were just slightly negative? What would that mean about the power consumption of the device?

Comment: @ThePhoton Sadly I don’t have an answer to this one:(

Comment: Try drawing the I-V curve of the device with the "-1" removed. What is the difference between quadrants I and III of an I-V graph vs quadrants II and IV?

Comment: @ThePhoton I think without -1 the increasing negative Vbe makes Ies zero; but with -1 it settles to -Ies

Comment: If you are interested in the details of its development, I can refer you to Shockley's paper, ["The Theory of *p*-*n* Junctions in Semiconductors and *p*-*n* Junction Transistors"](https://archive.org/details/bellsystemtechni28amerrich/page/434). There, you will find the term simplified towards the value of 1 through the extraction of terms around page 450 or so. I'd rather let the mathematics there explain where it comes from. Any quick words I would use would over-simplify to the point of distortion. It's a real effect, though. Not just a math trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the Schockley Diode Equation, if you want to look it up.  If you're an EE student sit up and pay attention in your solid-state quantum mechanics class -- you'll end up deriving this one there.

The 1 comes from the rate of electron-hole pair generation in the junction; it is constant over voltage (although not over temperature -- I was in the industry for about 5 years before I realized that \$I_{ss}\$ is temperature dependent.  I felt cheated that I was not told sooner).

The \$e^\frac{V_{BE}}{V_T}\$ part is from the rate of recombination of hole-electron pairs; it is exponential with voltage, and exactly matches electron-hole pair generation at \$V_{BE} = 0\$ (as one would hope it would).